# Silverlight 4 Datagrid Sorting

Tags: silverlight, sorting, datagrid

I'm having a heck of a time trying to get a silverlight datagrid to properly sort, and do so quickly (sub 1/10 second).  Here's the scenario:

-WCF callback every 1/5 of a second
-Take the callback, match up to the existing record in an ObservableCollection
-Update the ObservableCollection's properties
-Bind the grid.

I've tried a linq query, PagedCollectionView, and observablecollection.select(), all are waaaaaaay too slow, and introduce 12+ second delays in processing.  Anyone else experience this?

Comment: How many records are you sorting?

Comment: 50 records.  Should be fast, but it's not......

Comment: When you tried the PagedCollectionView what are you using the SortDescriptions collection to do the sorting or are you manually sorting and creating a new PagedCollectionView?  Also can you elaborate on what the WCF callback is doing?  What is it changing that means the DataGrid should be resorted.

Comment: WCF service responds with an updated Object, it has roughly 20 properties, I'd say maybe 8-10 are changed every 1/2 second.  I was using SortDescriptions.  Page loads, I set the pagedcollectionview, then the sortdescriptions, then the itemssource of the grid...everything updates except the sort

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calling PagedCollectionView.Refresh from a separate timer works.  This prevents the Refresh call from getting called every 1/10 of a second (which is the frequency of callbacks in my scenario).

Answer (score 0):

Use PagedCollectionView, but only set it once.  Create one view at application startup and then in your WCF callback update the objects instead of creating new ones.  Then call `Refresh()` on your CollectionView.

Comment: I did this, but it still takes to long, well over 1/10th of a second.  Can you think of anything else?  For the mean time I took PagedCollectionView.Refresh and tossed it inside of its own timer with a callback.  It works ok, but I'm pretty disappointed that we can't sort 50 records efficiently.

Comment: Are you changing the source collection at all?  If you change the source collection at all it forces the DataGrid to rebuild it's whole structure.

Comment: Yes, I'm updating the collection with the latest data...the records are the same, just updating properties

Comment: If the PagedCollectionView.Refresh() is too slow then I doubt you will be able to get it faster.